# Cannot connect from Visual Studio to CRM 2013 on Premise. Authentication failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Visual Studio 2012 and a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013. I use the CRM SDK Visual Studio plugin to connect my VS to the CRM. On my machine it works, on my colleagues machine it does not work. He gets the following error message when clicking the login button:

```
The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed
```

I set up all machines and my Windows client machine was added to the domain automatically. We added his machine, too (via Active Directory Users and Computers) but that did not help. We both use either default credentials or login with the domain administrator (domain\administrator) with the same results.

What do I have to configure to enable my colleague to login, too?

Detail information: Server is a Win2012 R2 Server, clients are both Win7.

Cheers,
Arne

Comment: Does your colleague have CRM account? Can he access CRM in browser?

Comment: Yes he can access the CRM in a browser. He uses the administrator account of the domain for that and it works perfectly. When he enters the same credentials to the VS prompt it fails.

Comment: Have you already tries to run VS from your colleague's machine with Admin credentials (Right Click on icon > run as Administrator)?

Comment: Yes we did that, did not work.

Comment: Is it possible that your colleague machine has some firewall issue?

Comment: No, he has both firewalls turned off, on the client with the VS running and on the server with the CRM running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem. A look in the appropriate place in the event log showed that the Visual studio sends the wrong credentials when the login is performed
during startup of VS. When that is canceled, the startup completes and afterwards the connection to the CRM is made, VS sends the correct credentials
and the login works.

I hope that helps someone to save some time.

Cheers,
Arne

Comment: How to check the username and password being used by the visual studio? I am facing the same issue. CRM is installed on another server which is a different domain than the development machine user. I am trying to connect to CRM using SDK and provided my username and password. I am able to access the CRM via a browser from my machine.